# Property assignment doesn't work

Tags: javascript, cordova, variable-assignment

I'm quite new to Javascript and I feel like I am missing something about assignments.
I have a variable "users" of type "SQLResultSetRowList" which is actually the result of a SELECT SQL request and that represents the users of my application (I'm working with Phonegap if that's of any relevance).

When I do

```
users.item(0).name = "foo";
```

It doesn't actually change the property name of my first user to "foo", it remains the same. It also returns "foo" (which is normal I think).

I found a solution that consist in "copying" the object

```
var newObj = {id: users.item(0).id, ... , name: users.item(0).name};
newObj.name = "foo";
```

but it feels really dirty.
Could you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use square bracket users.item[0].name = "foo";

Comment: @NitinDhomse is that a guess or...? The [docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.7.0/cordova/storage/sqlresultsetrowlist/sqlresultsetrowlist.html) specify `To get a row of data you would call the item method specifying an index`

Comment: What is the data type of `users`? Is it an array? It looks like `item` is a method that returns another object of type `users` which also has a property `name` in it.

Comment: @Jamiec sorry, I thought its a javascript object.

Comment: You need to make a copy and alter the copy.

Comment: @epascarello That's what I did but I don't understand why I have to do that. It feels really dirty

Comment: Because it is immutable

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. Just saw the duplicate label over my question. Too bad I didn't find it earlier. Have a nice day.